# HttpContext is null when send a request from axios

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpcontext

I am trying to fetch user from my backend, when I am send a request to my controller from backend them HttpContext.User is coming with data. But when I am trying to fetch user from frontend with axios, HttpContext.User is null and data is not returning.

Here is my get User method in Controller:

```
        [HttpGet("me")]
        public IActionResult GetMe()
        
        {
            var claims = HttpContext.User.Claims.Select(c => new { c.Type, c.Value }).ToList();
            return Ok(claims);
        }
```

Here is my authentication configuration in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("cookie").AddCookie("cookie").AddOAuth("Discord", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "cookie";
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Discord:ClientId");
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Discord:ClientSecret");
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize";
    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token";
    options.CallbackPath = "/oauth/discord-cb";
    options.Scope.Add("identify");
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://discord.com/api/users/@me";
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "username");

    options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = async ctx =>
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, ctx.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ctx.AccessToken);

        var response = await ctx.Backchannel.SendAsync(request);
        var user = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<JsonElement>();
        ctx.RunClaimActions(user);
    };
});
```

```
app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext ctx) =>
{
    ctx.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

    return ctx.User.Claims.Select(x => new { x.Type, x.Value }).ToList();
});

app.MapGet("/login", () =>
{
    return Results.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "http://localhost:3000"
    }, authenticationSchemes: new List<string>() { "Discord" });
});
```

I also set Cors Policy, and tried this:

```
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public AuthController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        [HttpGet("me")]
        public IActionResult GetMe()
        
        {
            var claims = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.Select(c => new { c.Type, c.Value }).ToList();
            return Ok(claims);
        }
```

Backend is running on: https://localhost:5005/    (C# Asp.Net Core)
Fronend is running on: http://localhost:3000/     (Vue.js)

When I am go to this url: https://localhost:5005/api/auth/me this is the result: [image]

Comment: So `HttpContext` is *not* null, it has a valid value. It's `HttpContext.User` that's null, probably because the request isn't authenticated. `data is not returning` that's because trying to call a method on a null would result in a NullReferenceException. All the actions in the question allow anonymous calls

Comment: You need to add the `Authorize` attribute to the controller actions to force the caller to authenticate